# Error item undefined when using with_items

Tags: ansible

I'm trying to create a new playbook which should add some lines in to a existing file. Unfortunately my playbook does not work.

```
---
- 
  name: 'Playbook to update limits in 20-nproc.conf'
  remote_user: lwa
  strategy: free
  gather_facts: no
  become: yes
  hosts: "{{ target }}"

  tasks:
    -
      name: 'Updating limits for oracle user for Oracle DB installation'
      lineinfile:
        path: /etc/security/limits.d/20-nproc.conf
        line: '{{ item }}'
        state: present
        insertafter: EOF
        backup: yes
        create: no
        owner: root
        group: root
        mode: '644'
        with_items:
          - '#<domain>      <type>  <item>         <value>'
          - 'oracle         soft    nofile         4096'
          - 'oracle         hard    nofile         63536'
          - 'oracle         soft    nproc          2047'
          - 'oracle         hard    nproc          16384'
          - 'oracle         soft    stack          10240'
          - 'oracle         hard    stack          32768'
```

Answer (score 0):

I finally got it. I used the blockinfile module instead the lineinfile.

```
---
- 
  name: 'Playbook to update limits in 20-nproc.conf'
  remote_user: lwa
  strategy: free
  gather_facts: no
  become: yes
  hosts: "{{ target }}"

  tasks:
    -
      name: 'Insert/Update limits for oracle user for Oracle DB installation'
      blockinfile:
        path: /etc/security/limits.d/20-nproc.conf
        block: |
          #<domain>      <type>  <item>         <value>
          oracle         soft    nofile         4096
          oracle         hard    nofile         63536
          oracle         soft    nproc          2047
          oracle         hard    nproc          16384
          oracle         soft    stack          10240
          oracle         hard    stack          32768
        state: present
        insertafter: EOF
        backup: yes
        create: no
        owner: root
        group: root
        mode: '644'
```